# Does there exists values of x for $f(x) = x^{2} e^{\frac{1}{(1-x^2)}}$ when $f(x)=1$ in $(-1,1)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

Given $ \; \large{f(x)=x^{2} e^{\frac{1}{(1-x^2)}}} \; \; $ has solutions for $ f(x)=1 $ in $(-1,1)$. I think there are no solutions, but I am not sure how to prove it. Can anyone please help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: At least $f(0)=0$. yeah?

Comment: @MohammadKhosravi so it has a solution

Comment: what do you mean by having solutions? I cannot see any equation to be solved in your question, do you mean solutions for $f(x)=0$?

Comment: @mastrok sorry edited i mean f(x)=1 .

Comment: IT has no solutions in that interval because an exponential functions is never zero. In this case there are two functions multiplying and only x^2 approach zero faster which does not imply that f(x) goes to zero.

Comment: Of course there are at least $2$ solutions. It is an even function, so just look at the range $[0,1]$. $f(0) =0$ and $f(0.9) \approx 156$, $f(x)$ is continuous, by intermediate value theorem, there has to be a solution in $[0,1]$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

If you look for the roots of $$f(x)=x^{2} e^{\frac{1}{1-x^2}}-1=0$$ consider its derivative; after some minor simplifications, it writes $$f'(x)=2x\frac{  \left(x^4-x^2+1\right)}{\left(x^2-1\right)^2}e^{\frac{1}{1-x^2}}$$ which has only $x=0$ as real root and $f(0)=-1$. The second derivative test would show that this is a minimum. Since, $f(x)$ goes to $\infty$ when $x$ approaches $\pm 1$, then two roots in the interval .

Comment: so f=1 has two solutions in (-1,1)

Comment: Please add the fact that $f(x)$ is an even function with positive derivative on $(0,1)$. This shows that it is monotone on $(-1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ and thus there exist unique solution in each of these intervals.

Answer (score 1):

Hint :

Study the function $ \; \large{f(x)=x^{2} e^{\frac{1}{(1-x^2)}}} \; \; $

Starting from $f(0)=0$, prove that the function is increassing in $x>0$ and decreassing in $x<0$

[image]